# Did something happen with the Month function?

Tags: formula, reporting, report-formula

I am trying to create a Row Level Report formula to give me the Opportunity Created Month. Below is a picture of the formula I am using.

[image]

This has always worked before. Do you all know if something has changed or if I am doing anything wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing's changed that I'm aware of.

But at any rate, the error spells it out for you. `MONTH()` requires a `Date`, and you've given it `CreatedDate` which despite the name is a `Datetime`. You're trying to push a square peg through a round hole.

You just need an extra function in there to extract just the Date component of the Datetime. `DATEVALUE()` is what you need.

So your formula should start with `CASE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)), ...`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much @Derek F. You rock!